# Wrongly closed as Duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[Is it illegal for a university to stock all Core and Recommended books, but provide Alternative Formats for only Core?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/27528/17516) doesn't duplicate [How can I challenge university's policy to provide Alternative Formats for only "Core" books?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/27192/17516). The other doesn't have this crucial fact:

> Our policy is to buy all Core and Recommended course reading material in electronic format if available, and in print.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how that statement is "crucial" (or even relevant) to the request for legal information that can be expected on this Stack Exchange.

In any case: if not closed as a duplicate, your question would be closed as a request for legal advice.